# Making fields/constructors PRIVATE or PUBLIC or NEITHER in object classes for de-serializing JSON using GSON?

Tags: java, json, oop, styles, gson

I've written a simple program that retrieves weather data from OpenWeatherMap API and de-serializes the JSON response into objects. One of the objects is called CurrentForecast. Here is a snippet of the class:

```
public class CurrentForecast {
    String name;
    long dt;
    LocationCoord coord;
    List<WeatherObject> weather;
    MainInfo main;
    WindInfo wind;

    public static class LocationCoord {
        Double lon;
        Double lat;

        public LocationCoord(Double lon, Double lat) {
            this.lon = lon;
            this.lat = lat;
        }
    }

    public static class WeatherObject {
        String description;

        public WeatherObject(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }

    public static class MainInfo {
        Double temp;
        Double temp_min;
        Double temp_max;
        Double pressure;
        Double humidity;

        public MainInfo(Double temp, Double pressure, 
                        Double humidity) {
            this.temp = temp;
            this.pressure = pressure;
            this.humidity = humidity;
        }
```

There are several classes nested within the CurrentForecast class. The fields of CurrentForecast and the nested classes were not set to private or public. I also didn't include a constructor for CurrentForecast to initialize 'name' and 'dt'. I also noticed that if I don't include the constructors for the other nested classes, the JSON data is de-serialized just fine.

My question is, do I set the fields for CurrentForecast and the nested classes to private and include get methods? Do I also have to include constructors or can I take those out?

Would love to get input on how I can properly set up my object classes (specifically for de-serializing JSON data using GSON in the main driver) and improve my programming style. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Should you set the fields to private and include getters?**

There's no need to, especially if other people aren't going to use your code, but I think it's good practice to do so since it helps to keep things neat. Up to you! Obviously keep in mind the circumstances; if you have a variable that you only want the class it resides in to have access to it, make it private.

**Do you have to include constructors?**

If you don't need some code to run when your class is instantiated (when you create a new object from a class), then there's no need to create a constructor since Java will create a default (non-parameterized) one for you.

I don't know much about GSON and de-serializing JSON data, but I think getters and setters would be beneficial in this situation to quickly be able to set and get your different variables without the code getting too messy.

Hope that helps!